# Onsen UI menu.SetMainPage is working but giving error which is causing strange behaviour in Phonegap Developer App

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, onsen-ui

Here is the error that function is giving. After this error click events stopped working. In fact I had to force exit the app. But it is working very fine in Google Chrome desktop with this error.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Class.module.factory.Class.extend._destroyEventListeners (onsenui.js:10926)
    at Class.module.factory.Class.extend._destroy (onsenui.js:10930)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$broadcast (angular.js:14438)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$destroy (angular.js:14062)
    at Class.module.factory.Class.extend._appendMainPage (onsenui.js:12139)
    at module.factory.Class.extend.setMainPage (onsenui.js:12221)
    at processQueue (angular.js:12914)
    at angular.js:12930
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:14123)
    at Scope.$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:13939)angular.js:11358 (anonymous function)angular.js:8445 $getangular.js:14440 $get.Scope.$broadcastangular.js:14062 $get.Scope.$destroyonsenui.js:12139 module.factory.Class.extend._appendMainPageonsenui.js:12221 module.factory.Class.extend.setMainPageangular.js:12914 processQueueangular.js:12930 (anonymous function)angular.js:14123 $get.Scope.$evalangular.js:13939 $get.Scope.$digestangular.js:14227 $get.Scope.$applyonsenui.js:19547 click dblclick mousedown mouseup mouseover mouseout mousemove mouseenter mouseleave keydown keyup keypress submit focus blur copy cut paste.split.forEach.ngEventDirectives.(anonymous function).compile.listenerangular.js:3013 eventHandler
```

Comment: Coud you make a Codepen example that reproduces this error? You can fork this pen: http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/IDvFJ

Comment: Can't reproduce on this Codepen. That's a lot of code. It's just that every time menu.setMainPage('page.html', {id: some.id}); is triggered. The error occurs. I have Bootstrap, Jquery included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated the Onsen UI to 1.3.0 Solved my problem. Same thing is working very fine. I think there was some sort of bug in previous version of Onsen UI.